# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008

Tags: c++

I have been struggling with this for a while and was wondering if anyone could help.  I am trying to make a particle sample using C++ and SDL1.3 and I have had great success up until this point.  The program compiles and the screen opens and nothing happens. When I run the debugger I get this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x0102414a in SDL 1.3 Space.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.
The program '[7272] SDL 1.3 Space.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

and it points to this piece of the code:

```
bool particle::isDead()
{
    return (SDL_GetTicks() >= endTime || x == 0 || y == 0 || x == SDL_GetVideoSurface()->w -1 || y == SDL_GetVideoSurface()->h - 1);
}
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone would be so kind as to help me and /or point me in the right direction.

This is the entire program:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "common.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

/*static SDL_Texture *background = 0; //background
  SDL_Renderer *renderer;

void render()
{   
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, background, NULL, NULL); //Display background
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    endFrame = SDL_GetTicks();
};*/ 

class particle
{
    float x, y, xvel, yvel;
    Uint32 endTime;
    Uint8 color;

    public:
        particle( float X, float Y, float Xvel, float Yvel, int life, Uint8 Color  );
        void move();
        void show();
        bool isDead();
};

particle::particle( float X, float Y, float Xvel, float Yvel, int life, Uint8 Color )
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    xvel = Xvel;
    yvel = Yvel;
    endTime = SDL_GetTicks() + life;
    color = Color;
}

void particle::move()
{
    x += xvel;
    y += yvel;

    if ( x < 0 )
        x = 0;

    if ( y < 0 )
        y = 0;

    if ( x > SDL_GetVideoSurface() -> w)
        x = SDL_GetVideoSurface()  -> w - 1;

    if ( y > SDL_GetVideoSurface() -> h)
        y = SDL_GetVideoSurface()  -> h -1;
}

void particle::show()
{
    Uint8* pixels = (Uint8*) SDL_GetVideoSurface()->pixels;
    Uint8* pixel = pixels + (int) y * SDL_GetVideoSurface()->pitch + (int) x;
    *pixel = color;
}

bool particle::isDead()
{
    return (SDL_GetTicks() >= endTime || x == 0 || y == 0 || x == SDL_GetVideoSurface()->w -1 || y == SDL_GetVideoSurface()->h - 1);
}

class particleEngine
{
    std::vector <particle*> particles;
    int x, y, maxparticle;

    public:
        particleEngine( int maxpart, int X, int Y );
        ~particleEngine();
        void refresh();
};

particleEngine::particleEngine( int maxpart, int X, int Y )
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    maxparticle = maxpart;
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxparticle; i++ )
        particles.push_back (new particle( x + rand()%6-3, y + rand()%6-3, rand()%10 + (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 5, rand()%10 + (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 5, 500 + rand()%1000, 0));
}

particleEngine::~particleEngine()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxparticle; i++)
        delete particles[i];
}

void particleEngine::refresh()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxparticle; i++)
    {
        if ( particles[i]->isDead())
        {
            delete particles[i];
            particles[i] = new particle( x + rand()%6-3, y + rand()%6-3, rand()%10 + (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 5, rand()%10 + (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 5, 500 + rand()%1000, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            particles[i]->move();
            particles[i]->show();
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    bool running = true;
    const int FPS = 30;
    Uint32 startFrame;
    srand (time(0));
    particleEngine ps(1000, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);

    SDL_Window *window;         /* main window */
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)!= 0) 
    {
        printf("Could not initialize SDL");
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL 1.3 Particles", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    // Body of the program goes here.
    while (running)
    {
        startFrame = SDL_GetTicks();
        SDL_Event event;
        //render();
        //While there's events to handle
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            //If the user has Xed out the window
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) 
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }

    //SDL_FillRect(renderer, &renderer->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB(renderer->format, 0x00,0x00, 0x00));

    ps.refresh();
    //SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    //SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    if (1000/FPS>SDL_GetTicks()-startFrame)
        SDL_Delay(1000/FPS-(SDL_GetTicks()-startFrame));

}
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Access violations mean you are dereferencing null pointers(or pointers to memory you don't have access to), so this would mean (assuming the debugger synced with the source correctly) that `SDL_GetVideoSurface` is returning null, so you'll probably wanna throw a few checks in `isDead`. Secondly, its probably a good idea to store the w/h of the surface minus 1 in your class at during the creation of the surface, should mean a little less computational overhead along with shorter code.

Comment: followed throw with your idea of "store the w/h of the surface minus 1 in your class during the creation of the surface", but my chaecks are not coming back with anything... or I'm not checking properly. Do you have any other advise for me?

Comment: @JasonM: generally when I run into problems like this I step through it using a debugger, so if you have visual studio/gdb/olly you can always check why the function is going wonky. Also, checking into the APi a bit, you may wanna check `SDL_GetError` and `SDL_GetErrorMsg`

Comment: I have resolved the issue with the original line of code I pointed out earlier, but now the debugger isn't giving me any info at all.  When I researched what the problem may be it look likeit could be a .lib / .dll issue and I have taken all the steps to resolve that and still no change.  I have implemented the SDL_GetError and am kinda confused on the gdb/olly but I have installed it and ran it and that is where I think I found the .lib /.dll problem.  I'm totally lost now and would it be better to just start over again?

Comment: @JasonM: learning how to debug a code problem is one of the best skills to have, cause you'll likely run into something that requires it in the future, and one can't simply keep restarting everything.

Comment: Well I haven't giving up yet... I have just debugged  again after trying a few things and I have received this message " unable to init SDL: passed a NULL mutex ", I think this is new to me.