# Error "Access violation reading location 0x00000008" with msftedit.dll RichEdit control inside SetWindowSubclass

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have edit control in separate subclass file. After getting to work SetWindowSubclass function (I am new to C++ and previously I used SetWindowLongPtr for subclassing where it worked fine but I was given advice to start using SetWindowSubclass), I got this issue:

After compiling the program, application draws the empty window, which immediately stops responding (and I have to close it via Task Manager).
The result error in Output window:

> Exception thrown at 0x635F3DEF (msftedit.dll) in TaskTracklist.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

Whole code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "SearchEditBox.h"

/*global vars*/
LPCWSTR SearchEditBox::editBoxDefText = L"Search...";
bool SearchEditBox::firstLoad = false;
int SearchEditBox::width = 0;
int SearchEditBox::height = 0;
HWND SearchEditBox::editBox;

/*functions*/
LRESULT CALLBACK EditBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uint_ptr, DWORD dwRefData);
void ChangeEdit(const HWND hwnd, const bool change);

/*set-get functions*/
HWND SearchEditBox::getEditBox()
{
    return SearchEditBox::editBox;
}

SearchEditBox * SearchEditBox::CreateEditBox(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hwnd, int pos_x, int pos_y, int width, int height) {
    SearchEditBox * p_SearchEditBox = new SearchEditBox;

    LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll")); //enables RichEdit field
    SearchEditBox::editBox = CreateWindowEx(0, (L"RICHEDIT50W"), editBoxDefText, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, pos_x + 6, pos_y + 4, width, height, hwnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), p_SearchEditBox);
    SearchEditBox::width = width;
    SearchEditBox::height = height;

    if (SearchEditBox::editBox == NULL)
    {
        delete p_SearchEditBox;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem creating the Search box.", L"Error", 0);
        return 0;
    }

    SetWindowSubclass(SearchEditBox::editBox, SearchEditBox::EditBoxProc, 0, 0);

    return p_SearchEditBox;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK SearchEditBox::EditBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD dwRefData)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_SETFOCUS:
        {
            LPWSTR getText = new TCHAR[10];
            GetWindowText(hwnd, getText, 10);
            if (_tcscmp(getText, editBoxDefText) == 0)
            {
                SearchEditBox::ChangeEdit(hwnd, 1);
            }
            delete getText;
            break;
        }
        case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        {
            LPWSTR getText = new TCHAR[10];
            if (GetWindowText(hwnd, getText, 10) == 0)
            {
                SearchEditBox::ChangeEdit(hwnd, 0);
            }
            ::SetFocus(NULL);
            delete getText;
            break;
        }
        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            SearchEditBox::ChangeEdit(hwnd, 1);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            RECT rc;
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rc, 0);
            if (SearchEditBox::firstLoad == false)
            {
                SearchEditBox::ChangeEdit(hwnd, 0);
                ::SetFocus(NULL);
                SearchEditBox::firstLoad = true;
            }
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(33, 33, 33));
            SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);
            RoundRect(hdc, -6, -4, SearchEditBox::width + 7, SearchEditBox::height + 4, 5, 5);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, lParam, wParam);
}
```

It is clear to me that the problem is with RichEdit control on line with SetWindowSubclass function.

Even though I did not find any topic related specifically to this error in connection to Msftedit.dll, I understood from these articles ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811882/0xc0000005-access-violation-reading-location-0x00000008) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665147/how-can-i-fix-this-error-access-violation-reading-location-0x00000008) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028420/0xc0000005-access-violation-reading-location-0x00000008-c-code)) that I may be referencing to NULL pointer, but that does not make sense to me because then I would get error from this bit just above SetWindowSubclass function (which I don't):

```
    if (SearchEditBox::editBox == NULL)
    {
        delete p_SearchEditBox;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem creating the Search box.", L"Error", 0);
        return 0;
    }
```

I also thought the problem may be with external function (meaning function defined in comctl32 and not inside class) accessing class specific variable (the pointer would **not** be NULL, but it just may not be accessible to the function somehow) so I tried creating local variable just for the SetWindowSubclass function (which did not work either):

```
HWND newHWND = SearchEditBox::editBox;
SetWindowSubclass(newHWND, SearchEditBox::EditBoxProc, 0, 0);
```

Using function getEditBox() did not solve that problem either.

I also tried using MSFTEDIT_CLASS instead of (L"RICHEDIT50W") in control declaration (thinking the problem may be inside the control itself) but that did not help either, and trying different versions (for example RICHEDIT51W or RICHEDIT80W) resulted in errors (so I must be working with the correct RichEdit version for VS2015).

I also tried declaring HWND editBox inside CreateEditBox (making it local variable), but that did not help either.

I use free Community version of VS.

EDIT: cleared some remains of my unsuccessful tries from the code.

Comment: Why are you doing `new TCHAR[10]` instead of just having `TCHAR getText[10];`?

Comment: @kfsone I copied this whole project from CodeBlocks where it worked fine with defining it as normal char and this was the first try that worked for me inside VS; I changed it in my file, thank you for suggestion!

Comment: Why are you assigning a `TCHAR[]` to a `LPWSTR` (aka `WCHAR*`) instead of a `LPTSTR` (aka `TCHAR*`)?  You are using the `TCHAR`-version of everything, so you should be consistent. Also, you need to use `delete[] getText;` instead of `delete getText;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Exception thrown at 0x635F3DEF (msftedit.dll) in TaskTracklist.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

An Access Violation near address 0 usually means that a class/record data member is being accessed via a NULL object pointer.

> Even though I did not find any topic related specifically to this error in connection to Msftedit.dll, I understood from these articles (...) that I may be referencing to NULL pointer, but that does not make sense to me because then I would get error from this bit just above SetWindowSubclass function (which I don't)

The problem is not related to accessing a NULL *`HWND` handle*.  It is related to accessing a NULL *object pointer* instead.  And you do have object pointers in your code, so you need to figure out which one is NULL.  When the AccessViolation happens, use the debugger to look at the code that is running at memory address 0x635F3DEF, that should lead you to which line in your code is crashing.

With that said, the last parameter of `EditBoxProc()` needs to be a `DWORD_PTR` instead of a `DWORD`, and you are passing the `wParam` and `lParam` values to `DefSubclassProc()` in the wrong order.

Also, your `WM_KILLFOCUS` and `WM_PAINT` handlers should not be calling `SetFocus()`, and your `WM_PAINT` handler should not be calling `InvalidateRect()`.

I suggest you re-write your `SearchEditBox` class so that its data members are not `static` anymore.  Making them `static` in the class prevents you from creating multiple `SearchEditBox` objects with individual `HWND`s.  The data members do not need to be `static`.  You can pass the `SearchEditBox*` pointer as the `dwRefData` parameter of the subclass so `EditBoxProc()` has access to the `SearchEditBox` object and its non-static members.

Try something more like this:

SearchEditBox.h

```
#ifndef SearchEditBoxH
#define SearchEditBoxH

class SearchEditBox
{
private:
    bool firstPaint;
    int width;
    int height;
    HWND editBox;

    SearchEditBox();
    void ChangeEdit(const bool change);

    static LRESULT CALLBACK EditBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uint_ptr, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

public:
    ~SearchEditBox();

    HWND getEditBox()

    static SearchEditBox* CreateEditBox(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hwnd, int pos_x, int pos_y, int width, int height);
};

#endif
```

SearchEditBox.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "SearchEditBox.h"

/*global vars*/
static LPCTSTR editBoxDefText = TEXT("Search...");

SearchEditBox::SearchEditBox()
{
    firstPaint = false;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    editBox = NULL;
}

SearchEditBox::~SearchEditBox()
{
    if (editBox)
        DestroyWindow(editBox);
}

void SearchEditBox::ChangeEdit(const bool change)
{
    //...
}

HWND SearchEditBox::getEditBox()
{
    return editBox;
}

SearchEditBox* SearchEditBox::CreateEditBox(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hwnd, int pos_x, int pos_y, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure RichEdit 4.1 is enabled
    if (!GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Msftedit.dll")))
    {
        if (!LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll")))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem loading Msftedit.dll.", L"Error", 0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    SearchEditBox *pSearchEditBox = new SearchEditBox;

    pSearchEditBox->editBox = CreateWindowEx(0, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, editBoxDefText, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, pos_x + 6, pos_y + 4, width, height, hwnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), p_SearchEditBox);
    if (!pSearchEditBox->editBox)
    {
        delete pSearchEditBox;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem creating the Search box.", L"Error", 0);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!SetWindowSubclass(pSearchEditBox->editBox, SearchEditBox::EditBoxProc, 0, (DWORD_PTR)p_SearchEditBox))
    {
        delete pSearchEditBox;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem subclassing the Search box.", L"Error", 0);
        return 0;
    }

    pSearchEditBox->width = width;
    pSearchEditBox->height = height;

    return pSearchEditBox;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK SearchEditBox::EditBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    SearchEditBox *pSearchEditBox = (SearchEditBox*) dwRefData;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, SearchEditBox::EditBoxProc, uIdSubclass);
            pSearchEditBox->editBox = NULL;
            break;

        case WM_SIZE:
            pSearchEditBox->width = LOWORD(lParam);
            pSearchEditBox->height = HIWORD(lParam);
            break;

        case WM_SETFOCUS:
        {
            TCHAR getText[10];
            GetWindowText(hwnd, getText, 10);

            if (_tcscmp(getText, editBoxDefText) == 0)
                pSearchEditBox->ChangeEdit(true);

            break;
        }

        case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        {
            TCHAR getText[10];
            if (GetWindowText(hwnd, getText, 10) == 0)
                pSearchEditBox->ChangeEdit(false);
            break;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            pSearchEditBox->ChangeEdit(true);
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            if (!pSearchEditBox->firstPaint)
            {
                pSearchEditBox->firstPaint = true;
                pSearchEditBox->ChangeEdit(false);
            }

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(33, 33, 33));
            SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);
            RoundRect(hdc, -6, -4, pSearchEditBox->width + 7, pSearchEditBox->height + 4, 5, 5);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            break;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Well there was actually no object with NULL pointer, the whole thing was caused by accidentally switching wParam and lParam in DefSubclassProc (4 hours wasted on absolute nonsense!). Remy thank you for all your advice, I will go through it step by step and implement all of it, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I have one additional question: why WM_PAINT handler should not be calling InvalidateRect()? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @DanielMaczak: Calling `InvalidateRect` will eventually cause the system to generate a `WM_PAINT` message. Your GUI thread will then be constantly busy rendering (you should see one CPU core running near 100% utilization).

Comment: @IInspectable well I was using that because for some reason I can't see text in the control without it. It seems like the RoundRect is covering it somehow because I can write, just can't see the text. Do you know of solution to this please? I tried to look it up but google remains silent to my cries :)

Comment: If you want to draw a rounded rectangle behind/around the text, you should handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` instead and not handle `WM_PAINT` at all. If you handle `WM_PAINT` then you have to draw the text as well, which you are not doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau <3 Thank you