# C++ Winapi - wrapping up a callback of subclass in a class

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019, subclassing

I wanted to create a class that I will be used to create a static control. The problem is when subclassing the control, the callback should be static which means I won't be able to access non-static variables and function inside the callback.

I've been pulling my hair to make my code works but still no success.

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(){
    non_static_variable = 0; //default is zero.
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::SubClassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {

    MyClass* pThis = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(dwRefData);
    
    char buffer[5];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "The value of non_static_variable is: %d \n", pThis->non_static_variable);
    OutputDebugStringA(buffer);    
        
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
            // do nothing for now
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_NCDESTROY: {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, SubClassProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;
        }
    }        
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void MyClass::CreateStaticControl(HWND WindowHandle) {
    
    StaticControl = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_OWNERDRAW, x, y, width, height, WindowHandle, NULL, NULL, this); 
    SetWindowSubclass(StaticControl, &SubClassProc, ID, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this));
}

void MyClass::SetValue(int value){
    non_static_variable = value; //test if I can access this in callback
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#include "header.h"

public:
    MyClass();

    void CreateStaticControl(HWND window);
    void SetValue(int value);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK SubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

private:
    int non_static_variable;
    HWND StaticControl;

};
```

Then call the class inside my `WM_CREATE` from my main window procedure, I used it like this.

```
...
case WM_CREATE:{
   MyClass myClass;
   myClass.CreateStaticControl(hwnd);
   myClass.SetValue(888);
   break;
}
```

You might think that this is a duplicate of others, I found a lot of them but since this is about subclassing and I don't have access to `WM_NCCREATE` I can't properly set the pointer of my class. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:** I put the exact code I have.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -I tried `MyClass* pThis = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(dwRefData);` and it gives me error of `read access violation, pThis was nullptr`.

Comment: That's because you passed 0 as the `dwRefData` when you called `SetWindowSubclass`. You probably meant to pass `(DWORD_PTR)this`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Access violation reading location 0x00000008" with msftedit.dll RichEdit control inside SetWindowSubclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357022/error-access-violation-reading-location-0x00000008-with-msftedit-dll-richedit)

Comment: @RaymondChen - I tried `SetWindowSubclass(StaticControl, &SubClassProc, ID, (DWORD_PTR)this);` then cast `MyClass* pThis = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(dwRefData);`, the code runs, however, I wans't able to get the value of non-static variable.

Comment: @Bolomeo then you are still doing something wrong with it, but we can't see everything you are doing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Moving the declaration of your `MyClass myClass;` outside `WM_CREATE` will solve the issue. Try to make it global instead. `MyClass myClass; CALLBACK YouMainWndProc(...){...case WM_CREATE:{...myClass.SetValue(888);}}`

Comment: @Polar, That solved the issue indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dwRefData` parameter of `SetWindowSubclass()` to pass the `this` pointer to the `dwRefData` parameter of the callback. You can then type-cast that parameter to access non-static members. No need to use `GWLP_USERDATA` at all (especially since you are not using the callback's `lParam` correctly when setting `GWLP_USERDATA`).

Try this instead:

MyClass.h

```cpp
class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass();

    void CreateStaticControl(HWND window);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK SubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

private:
    int non_static_variable;
    HWND StaticControl;

};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```cpp
void MyClass::CreateStaticControl(HWND WindowHandle) {
    StaticControl = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_OWNERDRAW, x, y, width, height, WindowHandle, NULL, NULL, this); 
    SetWindowSubclass(StaticControl, &SubClassProc, ID, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::SubClassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {

    MyClass* pThis = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(dwRefData);
        
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
                
            // use pThis->non_static_variable as needed...
                
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_NCDESTROY: {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, SubClassProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;
        }
    }        

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: That makes the code runs, however, the value of `int non_static_variable;` is incorrect. I tried to initialize it in `void MyClass::CreateStaticControl(HWND WindowHandle) { non_static_variable = 888;}` and I get `0` in my subclass callback.

Comment: @Bolomeo Then you are doing something else wrong with it, like maybe calling `CreateStaticControl()` on an invalid `MyClass` object. We can't see everything you are doing. Please update your question with a [mcve] showing how you create the `MyClass` object and call `CreateStaticControl()` on it, and how you access `non_static_variable`.

Comment: I put the exact code I have and your suggestion, Including on how I used the class, please have a look.

Comment: @Bolomeo your `MyClass` object is a local variable inside a `WM_CREATE` handler. It will be destroyed when the handler exits. But `MyClass` does not have a destructor that destroys the STATIC control and removes the subclass. So the STATIC control lives on, and the subclass callback will be accessing an invalid `MyClass` object. The `MyClass` object needs to outlive the subclass, not the other way around.